# How many sub-domain are allowed for an Email Id?

Tags: subdomain, validation, email-address

How many subdomains are possible for an Email address?
For Example: `something@something.co.uk.uk`
like that....

Comment: This doesn't seem on topic here... maybe superuser?

Comment: Actually i want to validate the Email Address in my Web Application. So it is required for me to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any constraints based on subdomain count.

There is limitation of lengths parts of e-mail address in [RFC821](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc821.html)

> **user**
>
> The maximum total length of a user name is 64 characters.
>
> **domain**
>
> The maximum total length of a domain name or number is 64 characters.
>
> **path**
>
> The maximum total length of a reverse-path or forward-path is 256 characters (including the punctuation and element separators).

limitations in [RFC2821](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2821.html)

> **local-part**
> The maximum total length of a user name or other local-part is 64
> characters.
>
> **domain**
> The maximum total length of a domain name or number is 255
> characters.

and newest in [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1)

> 4.5.3.1.1. **Local-part**
>
> The maximum total length of a user
> name or other local-part is 64
> octets.
>
> 4.5.3.1.2. **Domain**
>
> The maximum total length of a
> domain name or number is 255 octets.
>
> 4.5.3.1.3. **Path**
>
> The maximum total length of a
> reverse-path or forward-path is 256
> octets (including the punctuation and
> element separators).

Comment: +1, but note that this RFC was superseded by [RFC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1) and the limits are now much larger.

Comment: @Mike, thank you. I've added information from RFC5321 in my answer.